# Can i get postion using getCurrentItem() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using ViewPager for my application.Kindly suggest me  that it is possible to get current fragment position by calling getCurrentItem() method in fragment.

```
The Code is :-


@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume(); 
           // i am also try this code but its giving me nullpointer exception but ican    get viewpager object here.

         int pos=_mypager.getCurrentItem();

    }
```

Kindly suggest me how can i take current fragment position in fragment.

Comment: If you are getting a NullPointerException, your variable _mypager isn't initialized.

Comment: the variable is ititailize i got viewpager object value.

Comment: Can you post some more complete code?